# xcopy /D flag copying all files instead of newer/newer files

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm trying to make a simple batch file to "sync" everything between a file on my onedrive, and a file on a network drive.

I want to be able to run the batch file, and anything new on the onedrive will be copied to the network drive, but not the other way around.

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
echo : XCOPY started
xcopy "D:\OneDrive - Radford University\Classwork 2017-2018\Spring 2018" "H:\Spring 2018" /E /D /C /Y /EXCLUDE:C:\exclude.txt
echo : complete
```

when run, this file seems to copy anywhere between 80-83 files. It is different each time I run it, despite me making no changes to either directory.

My understanding is that the /D flag for xcopy will ensure that it only copies files that are new, or have a newer modified date. But in this case, it seems to copy everything that isn't in my exclude.txt, regardless of date modified.

Comment: I usually just use the /M switch.  When a file is created or modified the archive attribute is set.  So if you just tell XCOPY to only copy those files you should be fine.  Regardless of that you should consider just using Robocopy instead.

Comment: /M produced even worse results, with 120 files being copied. Robocopy looks good, but I can't find any way to get it to exclude keywords like /exclude does for xcopy

Comment: Run it again and I bet it doesn't copy anything. It will turn off the archive attribute after the copy.

Comment: Robocopy has two switches you can use to exclude.  /XF and /XD.

Comment: How many files are listed in your c:\excludes.txt file?  How many bytes total?

Comment: @Squashman, running it again produces the same results every time. And the exclude file only has 3 lines.

Comment: @SajidAnsari, then you must have one of those special computers that does things only on your computer.  Just like my mom's computer until I go over there and do the same thing and it magically works.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to be passive aggressive. I will provide a screenshot of two identical runs, if that is really necessary

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the two options:

```
    for /f %%G in (c:\exclude.txt) do set "_excludes=%_excludes% %%~G"
    robocopy "D:\OneDrive - Radford University\Classwork 2017-2018\Spring 2018" "H:\Spring 2018" /MT /E /MIR /XF %_excludes%
```

or

```
    robocopy "D:\OneDrive - Radford University\Classwork 2017-2018\Spring 2018" "H:\Spring 2018" /MT /E /MIR
    for /f %%G in (c:\exclude.txt) do del "%%~G"
```

You test with the `/L` option to simply log what it would have done.

Comment: Awesome, this works, except for the fact that the exclude function does not appear to work. I only tried the first solution, as the second one involves copying and then deleting afterwards, which seems inefficient.